# Gif of US map ggplots using Yearly data in R

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, maps, animated-gif

My data frame has 30 years of revenue data of an entity for each US state.
I am trying to generate a GIF of the US map which displays how the revenue of each state has changed over 30 years.

I tried the below options, but somehow running into errors. Hopefully, somebody can help!

Option 1:- Seems like the below code might work, but I think I need to install  Image Magick software to generate the gif file. I am waiting for my IT team's green signal. Meanwhile, please correct me if I went wrong anywhere!

```
uniq<-unique(new_map$Year)

Rev_Animate<-function(){
lapply(uniq,function(i){
data_1 <- subset(new_map, Year == uniq)
ggplot(data=data_1,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,frame=Year,fill=Revenue_Res),
                       alpha=0.8,color = "black")
+geom_polygon()})}

saveGIF(Rev_Animate(),interval=.65,movie.name = "YRev.gif")
```

Option 2:- I used gganimate (assuming it doesn't need Image Magick), but I get this error:
"Error in file(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection".
Googled to fix the error(restart R, Re-install packages used etc) but nothing seems to be working in my case!

Code with gganimate:

```
q<- ggplot(data=new_map,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,frame=Year,fill=Revenue_Res),alpha=0.8,color = "black")
+geom_polygon()
gganimate(q)
```

Sample Data:

```
new_map<-structure(list(region = c("alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama", 
"alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama", 
"alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama", 
"alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama"), long = c(-87.4620056152344, 
-87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, 
-87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, 
-87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, 
-87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, 
-87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344, -87.4620056152344), lat = 
c(30.3896808624268, 
30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 
30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 
30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 
30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 
30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268, 30.3896808624268), group = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), order = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), subregion = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), Year = c(2016, 1998, 2007, 2001, 
2017, 2012, 1990, 2018, 2002, 1993, 1994, 2004, 2003, 1991, 1999, 
1996, 1992, 1995, 2011, 2008), State = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL"), `Data Status` = c("Final", "Final", 
"Final", "Final", "Preliminary", "Final", "Final", "Preliminary", 
"Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", 
"Final", "Final", "Final", "Final", "Final"), Revenue_Res = c(3843394.6, 
1896784, 3056790, 1950059, 3845072.5, 3491380, 1366083, 439880.31, 
2138395, 1544206, 1549858, 2295150, 2175026, 1424738, 1901353, 
1700371, 1413407, 1630852, 3661469, 3347563)), .Names = c("region", 
"long", "lat", "group", "order", "subregion", "Year", "State", 
"Data Status", "Revenue_Res"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Take a look at `gganimate`

Comment: When you get errors, you should post the errors. The error messages are usually very helpful.

Comment: At a glance, I think you have a syntax error when you have two commas in a row in `ggplot(data = data_1,,frame=Year)`. Also, I'm confused that you have both a a `for` loop and an `lapply`? Shouldn't one of those be enough?

Comment: I'm afraid said sample data is not sufficient to reproduce your problem; `new_map` is not included either.

Comment: @hrbrmstr my dataframe has ~450K records, so I only included 20 records in the sample!